# Reading from .txt files outputs System.String[] instead of intended outcome c#

Tags: c#

I have a .txt file which contains multiple numbers and I want it to read the file and output the numbers. But when it reads the file it outputs System.String[] instead of the numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] unsorted = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"\University\AlgRetake\Files\WS1_AF.txt");
        //Grabs the .txt file and reads line by line

        System.Console.WriteLine("Unsorted: ");
        foreach (string line in unsorted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(unsorted);
        }
        //outputs the unsorted array


        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit!");
        System.Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to write all of unsorted, rather than the actual line you're on. As arrays (even arrays of String) don't have a good toString implementation built-in, it just prints the type. Changing it to `Console.WriteLine(line)` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your foreach loop, you should have `Console.WriteLine(line);`

Otherwise, you are writing the string array object cast as a string to the console.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close - you need to output LINE.
ie - LINE is each array entry.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] unsorted = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"\University\AlgRetake\Files\WS1_AF.txt");
        //Grabs the .txt file and reads line by line

        System.Console.WriteLine("Unsorted: ");
        foreach (string line in unsorted)
        {
            ****Console.WriteLine(line);****
        }
        //outputs the unsorted array


        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit!");
        System.Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a nit: the asterisks, while they call attention to the code change, also render the code uncompilable.  It might make more sense to call out the change with a comment, just in case anybody tries to use your code directly.  +1 anyway.

Comment: Fair enough adv.  Never again.
I was trying to bold it ;)

Answer (score 0):

line as in existing answers
but this is more efficient as no overhead of reading to string[] unsorted

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth explaining why that is more efficient, and under what circumstances the difference in efficiency matters.